# What non-GUI programs use glib?

Tags: daemon, glib

What non-GUI programs (daemons) use [glib](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/glib/info)?

Comment: All that are written in C. Perhaps you meant "why"...

Comment: @Álvaro err no, lots of stuff doesn't use glib (not talking about libc here, glib the library that GTK and stuff is built on top of)

Comment: @spudd86: You are right, I was confused by the *GNU C Library* (glibc).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On my Ubuntu system apt-cache rdepends libglib2.0-0 gives me, among many others:

- amanda-server (backup software)
- bitlbee (IRC <-> various IM proxy)
- blktool (tool to tune block device parameters; not a daemon AFAIU)
- collectd (system statistics collection and monitoring daemon)
- consolekit (framework for defining and tracking users, sessions and seats)
- devicekit-disks (abstraction for enumerating block devices)
- devicekit-power (abstraction for power management)
- (I got bored at this point)

This lists package rather than actual binary dependencies; it's possible (but I don't think likely) that some of these packages ship GUI applications that depend on glib.

Let's take, say, consolekit and verify:

`dpkg -L consolekit` tells me the daemon is /usr/sbin/console-kit-daemon, and `ldd /usr/sbin/console-kit-daemon` tells me it depends on libglib, libgthread, libgmodule, libgobject, libgio, but no GUI stuff.  So here you are, a genuine daemon using glib.

Answer (score 10):

I use glib quite a bit in non-GUI programming, especially for FUSE filesystems. Lots of routines to complement glibc, things like hash tables, a linked list implementation, a cross-platform threading library - lots of useful stuff for general-purpose programming. I think of it like C's version of Boost.

Answer (score 1):

[Irssi](http://www.irssi.org/), an IRC client with support for scripts.

Answer (score 1):

[GStreamer](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/) is built upon GLib/GObject.

Answer (score 0):

Most notable in my memory is libpurple aside from its GUI counterpart Pidgin